# How to mask out elements of a mask with less than 2 pixel density?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I'm trying to de-noise the subtraction of two masks where there may be some shifting in the x and y axis between them. I would like to mask out the regions where the True values have less than 2 pixel density.

What I've tried so far is to shift the mask to the left (then I will do it for the other axis) and use the & operation, but then the true values get thinner. Here is an example of what I'm trying:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(123)
x = np.array([np.random.choice([True, False]) for i in range(16*16)]).reshape((16, 16))
x_shift_left = np.roll(x, -1, axis=1)
x_and = x & x_shift_left

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(13, 8))
ax1.imshow(x, cmap='gray')
ax2.imshow(x_shift_left, cmap='gray')
ax3.imshow(x_and, cmap='gray')
```

Result of imshow
[image]

Is there a way to shift the & operation to the right adding a True value so that the True values have the same size as x, but the isolated True values will be masked out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There ya go

```
def smooth(a):
    b =  (a & np.roll(a, -1, axis=-1)) +  (a & np.roll(a, 1, axis=-1))
    b += (a & np.roll(a, -1, axis=1 )) +  (a & np.roll(a, 1, axis=1 ))
    return b > 0
```

and the result.
[image]